# Use of ast.literal_eval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I really do not understand the difference between the output of the two function that I've given below.
[image]

What is the use of **lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x) if isinstance(x,str) else np.nan** here ?

Comment: `print(type(df.spoken_languages[0]))` can you run this before and after using the function? What does it show as output?

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please do not post pictures of code or data; edit it into the question as text.

Before the `apply` call, the dataframe contains strings that look like Python objects. After the `apply` call, it contains actual Python objects. Unfortunately, Pandas pretty-prints dataframes in a way that makes it impossible to distinguish these two cases just by looking at the output.

(This is basically the inverse of the more common "how do I get rid of quotation marks when printing a list" question).

As an illustration, consider the following program. The output of `print(df.x)` looks the same before and after the `apply`, but the output of `print(type(...` is different.

```
import ast
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ["{'a': 17}"]})
print(df.x)
print(type(df.x[0]))
df.x = df.x.apply(ast.literal_eval)
print(df.x)
print(type(df.x[0]))
```